# Can wrapping a type conversion in a static_cast ever hurt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm updating some old code and I get hundreds of warnings along the lines of `warning C4244: '+=': conversion from 'std::streamsize' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data` in Visual Studio.

The project compiles and runs fine when just ignoring the warnings, but I want to remove them and put a `static_cast<unsigned long>()` function around each. Considering the code runs fine now, could this potentially be harmful?

Comment: If its a 32-bit project, you have to be able to guarantee the values of std::streamsize will never be negative otherwise you'll have issues when casting to an unsigned type.
If it is a 64-bit project you'll have to be able to make that guarantee as well as the guarantee that the value will never be greater than what a 32-bit unsigned long can hold.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `static_cast` can hurt, as it will tell the compiler to shut up, as you know what you are doing. The question is whether you actually know what you are doing?

Obviously, casting to a smaller type can result in an unexpected result if the stored data exceeds the smaller types size. Use a `static_cast` if you know for sure, that this case won't ever happen or that you expect a truncated value. If not, keep the warning until you have properly designed your code.

Answer (score 2):

> The project compiles and runs fine when just ignoring the warnings

To start with, never ignore warnings. Think over what your code actually does instead.

---

> Considering the code runs fine now, could this potentially be harmful?

Regarding your particular case, a `static_cast<unsigned long>` from `std::streamsize` will be harmful.

As the reference documentation of [`std::streamsize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize) says, it's intentionally a `signed` type:

> > The type `std::streamsize` is a **signed** integral type used to represent the number of characters transferred in an I/O operation or the size of an I/O buffer. It is used as a **signed** counterpart of `std::size_t`, similar to the POSIX type `ssize_t`.

Static casting in that case actually means *loss of semantics*.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that conversions allowed by static_cast are somewhat less
>   likely to lead to errors than those that require reinterpret_cast. In
>   principle, it is possible to use the result of a static_cast without
>   casting it back to its original type, whereas you should always cast
>   the result of a reinterpret_cast back to its original type before
>   using it to ensure portability.

from [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast)

Be careful with `const`s. `static_cast` doesn't cast away `const`.

In general, I think it would be better to rewrite your code instead of "casting every problem away" in hope that everything goes well.